# Require js error handling

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am developing a backbone js application.

I like to know how do I handle the requireJS errors.

In low internet speed requireJS generate errors like "timeout", "module not loaded" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an entire section about it on their page.

**[Handling Errors](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors)**

> *The general class of errors are 404s for scripts (not found), network
>   timeouts or errors in the scripts that are loaded. RequireJS has a few
>   tools to deal with them: require-specific errbacks, a "paths" array
>   config, and a global requirejs.onError.*

Comment: I have one another problem. The require js start loading the other js after few second. Do you have any idea related to this?